# Sql show 10 results where type = x and 10 results where type= y

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to get these two statements into one query?

```
   $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM angebote where (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND art = 'biete' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 18");

   $p = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM angebote where (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND art = 'suche' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 18");
```

doesn't seem to work with UNION or UNION ALL

SO when I tried

```
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM angebote where (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND art = 'biete' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 UNION
                SELECT * FROM angebote where (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND art = 'biete' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

it says Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:.....

Comment: Union should work properly. What have you tried as a union ?

Comment: well I just put them into one query seperated by a UNION like
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM angebote where (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND art = 'biete' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 18 UNION SELECT......");

Comment: and what was the error ? You should show what you have tried so far

Comment: yes, just use OR between `art`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) works fine here:

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT
      * 
    FROM 
      angebote
    WHERE 
      (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND 
      (art = 'biete')
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) as biete_tabelle

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT
      * 
    FROM 
      angebote
    WHERE 
      (city = '".$_POST['search']."' OR plz = '".$_POST['search']."') AND 
      (art = 'suche')
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) as suche_tabelle"
);
```

This will get you the results you look for. Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b10f/3) for an example.

*Note:* Though I sticked with german for consistency, I would like to advice you, that it is best bractice to use column and variable etc. names in english, so it is easier for developers that do not speak german to read your code.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, the problem is that this will give me 18 results, no matter how many of them are of type (art = suche) or (art = biete). It will take the latest 18 (since id is auto increment and it's ordered by it DESC)
But I would need exactly 18 of type (art = suche) and 18 of type (art = biete), Since art is either biete OR suche anyways, you could remove the whole AND statement but it would still deliver the 18 results, but without considering the amount of each type, hope that's understandable :/ I think in the end I will have to do it in a completely different way :P

Comment: @Svrex - Please have a look again.I updated the answer and the fiddle to the solution you are looking for. I misread your question at first, sorry for that

Comment: I think the problem you had were the missing alias that resulted in an sql error. Try removing them in the fiddle

Comment: YOU are the man! :D Works fine! you wouldn't believe how happy I am about this. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for the roses ;) glad I could help!